# Table with text, equations and diagrams

Tags: tables, diagrams

I'm trying to build a table containing text, equations and diagrams like this one:

[image]

I know how to make the diagrams using the figure+tikzpicture environment and also how to make tables with table+tabular environment. But just inserting one into the other didn't work.

Is there a standard solution for this?

Comment: And what you try so far?

Comment: @Zarko I've made the table the way I usually do and tried to insert the diagram in a cell, but it didn't work.

Comment: Dynkin diagrams can be conveniently produced with the `dynking-diagrams` package.

Comment: Well, thabn show what you try, then we can more easily help you. It may only need to be added `baseline` option to your picture,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
 text &  \dynkin[fold right,label,edge length=.75cm]D8 \\
\hline
 &  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got your solution using Tikz

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
Hello &  Tikz Diagram \\ \hline
This is text & 
%Now here i put the command \tikz, that allows you to draw outside tikzpicture and figure.
\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{% <-- Here I open tikz code.
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (1,0);
\fill (A) circle (2pt);
\fill (B) circle (4pt);
\draw (A) -- (B);
}% <-- Here I close the tikz code
\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Tikz in table]

Answer (score 1):

As suggested @abcdefg in his comment, use of `dynkin-diagrams` package can be very convenient for drawing your images in table. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edge length=8mm]{dynkin-diagrams}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{array}{|l|l|l|}
    \hline
r=0,1   &   I_3^*   &  \dynkin B3   \\
    \hline
r=0,1,2 &   I_2^*   &  \dynkin[label,
                               label macro/.code={\alpha_{\drlap{#1}}}]D5\\
    \hline
    \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

To make yourself more familiar with this package, read package documentation [Dynkin Diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572082/table-with-text-equations-and-diagrams)